# No class="active" on just some Pages

Tags: nodes, navigation

I'm on [Drupal 7.43](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/7.43) and are using [Nice Menus 7.x-2.5.](https://www.drupal.org/project/nice_menus/releases/7.x-2.5) I just noticed a problem but can't say it is connected to Nice Menu.

When I under `admin/structure/menus` manually creates menu links, not all links produces class="active". After a while I found a pattern:

1. All nodes created by a Content type, like node/53, works just fine,
   there are class="active" in the menus
2. Just some of the Pages made manually under admin/structure/pages
   produces class="active"
3. Pages with a functioning class="active" has a link with a Path name
   like "anypage"
4. Pages not producing class="active" has a link with a Path name like
   "/anypage". The difference is the /.

So why do I not write the Path without / ? Because it is impossible for some Pages. On some I can write without / and class="active" will appear, but on others when I try to write the Path without / I will have the message "The path 'anypage' is either invalid or you do not have access to it." When I add / in the beginning, I can create the link but there will be no class="active"

As far I can see there is no difference at all in the settings between the different pages.

Can anyone give me a lead what this is all about. Please, I really want the active class in the menu.

Comment: This looks like a panel issue (admin/structure/pages) and the path you are choosing. What are the url you are using? does these urls already exist? are the nodes published? do you have a multilingual site?

Comment: Multilingual site yes. The page URL is http://www.bjarstal.com/fr/pk_400_armoires_fortes_ignifuges_papier and the Path under https://www.bjarstal.com/fr/admin/structure/pages/edit/page-serie_pk_400_armoires_fortes_ignifuges_papier is /pk_400_armoires_fortes_ignifuges_papier

Comment: I found out how to solve it thanks to you asking if it is a multilingual site, but I still don't understand. In Access I had set it to: Accessible only if Site language is French and In Panel the setting is: This panel will be selected if Site language is "French". When I took away the Access rule all is fine,  BUT the Site language IS French and the selection rule works. Why did the Access rule kill it?